# Binding a number variable to a masked input in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Now that JSON parsing on my API requires my attributes to be strictly typed (ie ints need to be sent as numbers from javascript instead of attempting to parse the string), we are running into issues with the masks on our input boxes.

In particular, our currency mask is changing the bound variables to strings instead of keeping them as numbers.

Is it possible to bind a number to an input box, have that input box display non-numeric characters such as $, and keep the number strictly typed as a number? I tried forcing a parseFloat() on the getter but that did nothing to affect the type of the bound variable.

HTML:

```
<input appCurrencyMask [(ngModel)]="_variable" />
```

Mask:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, AfterViewInit, Input, forwardRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => { };

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyMaskDirective),
    multi: true
};

@Directive({
    selector: '[appCurrencyMask]',
    providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CurrencyMaskDirective implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    private el: HTMLInputElement;
    // Keeps track of the value without formatting
    private innerValue: any;
    private prefix: string;
    private decimalSeparator: string;
    private thousandsSeparator: string;
    // Optional Parameter to allow for negative number interaction
    @Input('allowNegative')
    allowNegative: boolean;
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.prefix = '$';
        this.decimalSeparator = '.';
        this.thousandsSeparator = ',';
    }

    // Placeholders for the callbacks which are later providesd
    // by the Control Value Accessor
    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (a: any) => void = noop;

    // set getter
    get value(): any {
        return parseFloat(this.innerValue.toString());
    }

    // set accessor including call the onchange callback
    set value(v: any) {
        if (v !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = v;
            this.onChangeCallback(v);
        }
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interface
    writeValue(value: any) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.el.value = this.transform(value, this.allowNegative);
            if (value) {
                this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
            }
            this.innerValue = parseFloat(value?.toString());
        }
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    // From ControlValueAccessor interface
    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.el.style.textAlign = 'right';
    }

    // On Focus remove all non-digit or decimal separator values
    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
    onfocus(value) {
        this.el.value = this.parse(value, this.allowNegative);
        if (this.el.value == "0") {
            this.el.value = "";
        }
    }

    // On Blue remove all symbols except last . and set to currency format
    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
    onBlur(value) {
        this.onTouchedCallback();
        this.el.value = this.transform(value, this.allowNegative);
        this.innerValue = this.parse(this.el.value, this.allowNegative);
        this.onChangeCallback(this.innerValue);
        if (this.innerValue) {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', this.innerValue);
        }
    }

    // On Change remove all symbols except last . and set to currency format
    @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value'])
    onChange(value) {
        this.el.value = this.transform(value, this.allowNegative);
        this.innerValue = this.parse(this.el.value, this.allowNegative);
        this.onChangeCallback(this.innerValue);
        if (this.innerValue) {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', this.innerValue);
        }
    }

    // Prevent user to enter anything but digits and decimal separator
    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
    onKeyPress(event) {
        const key = event.which || event.keyCode || 0;
        if (key === 45 && !this.allowNegative) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (key === 45 && this.allowNegative) {
            // allow negative numbers
        } else if (key !== 46 && key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    transform(value: string, allowNegative = false, decimalPrecision: number = 2) {
        if (value == undefined || value === '') {
            return "$0.00";
        }
        if (allowNegative) {
            value = value.toString();
            if (value.startsWith('(') || value.startsWith('-')) {
                value = '-' + value.substr(1, value.length).replace(/\(|\)|\$|\-/g, '');
            } else {
                value = value.replace(/\(|\)|\$|\-/g, '');
            }
        }
        let [integer, fraction = ''] = (value || '').toString().split(this.decimalSeparator);
        fraction = decimalPrecision > 0 ? this.decimalSeparator + (fraction + '000000').substring(0, 2) : '';
        if (integer.indexOf(',') < 0) { //thousandsSeparators have not been added yet
            if (!isNaN(parseInt(integer))) {
                integer = parseInt(integer).toString(); //remove leading 0s
            }
        }
        integer = integer.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, this.thousandsSeparator);

        // If user types .xx we can display 0.xx
        if (integer === '') {
            integer = '0';
        } else if (integer.startsWith('$')) {
            // If there are multiple transforms, remove the previous dollar sign (blur and change at the same time)
            integer = integer.substr(1, integer.length);
        } else if (allowNegative && integer.startsWith('-')) {
            // If user inputs negative number set to paranthesis format
            integer = integer.substr(1, integer.length);
            return '(' + this.prefix + integer + fraction + ')';
        }
        return this.prefix + integer + fraction;
    }

    parse(value: string, allowNegative = false) {
        let [integer, fraction = ''] = (value || '').split(this.decimalSeparator);
        integer = integer.replace(new RegExp(/[^\d\.]/, 'g'), '');
        fraction = parseInt(fraction, 10) > 0 && 2 > 0 ? this.decimalSeparator + (fraction + '000000').substring(0, 2) : '';
        if (allowNegative && value.startsWith('(') && value.endsWith(')')) {
            return (-1 * parseFloat(integer + fraction)).toString();
        } else {
            return integer + fraction;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your question, but from my understanding it seems like a [custom angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#creating-pipes-for-custom-data-transformations) is what you're looking for. Have you tried this?

Comment: no a pipe will not work for my purposes, I need the mask to apply within the control itself.

Comment: And my issue is that right now if my masked control displays "$80.15", my bound variable's value is not 80.15 (a number type), but "80.15" which is a string.

Comment: Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-bush-sbkgu?file=/src/app/app.component.ts) isn't what you're looking for? Why do you need the mask? Seems like it's doing the same work as a pipe

Comment: no. that would require me to write an input handler method in every component in my entire project. I want the mask to keep all this code in one easy place, and add it to individual components quickly and easily.

Comment: Well in a component-based architecture, the input with the pipe and input handler turns into a component that can be used and fed options from anywhere in your application. Either way, glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix, my

```
parse(value)
```

method was returning a string and thus setting the inner value to a string type. By adding a parseFloat() to the return value of the parse() method, I was able to achieve the desired result.

There is no issue with the input type being "text", that does not interfere with the data type of the bound variable.